# error: Update: :Extension: Could not open https://update.joomla.org/core/sts/extension_sts.xml

Tags: joomla-3.x, update, one-click-updates

im trying to update my Joomla from 3.4.5 to 3.4.8 but it doesn't work. 
it gives me this error:

Update: :Extension: Could not open https://update.joomla.org/core/sts/extension_sts.xml

I have no idea why, or what the solution is. Can anyone please help me?

Comment: This may be a temporary connection issue. Can you browse to https://update.joomla.org/core/sts/extension_sts.xml OK? It works for me at the moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't find a solution for this error, what i did was going to Joomla.org download page and download an 3.4.x to 3.4.8 package and installed in the Extensions manager and uploaded it this way. it works now.